# Why memory slots 3 and 4 won't work simultaneously?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Running Asus H170 Plus D3 motherboard on latest 2202 bios with 2 dual kits of CORSAIR Vengeance CMZ8GX3M1A1600C10 8GB

I can't get all 4 memory slots working - if all 4 slots are filled and enabled on bios I don't get video on monitor.

I would expect the reason to be one of slots to be malfunctioning, but that's not exactly the case.

Both memory slots 1/2 are working unless I disable them in bios.

Both memory slots 3/4 are working, if I leave one of them empty and disable that slot in bios and one of memory slots 1/2 is filled.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding 0.5 V to memory in BIOS settings.